# d3.js won't work in a shadowDOM

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dart, angular-dart, shadow-dom

I am building a tool that utilizes `d3.js` for data visualization. The tool relies on webcomponentss and the shadowDOM. `d3.js` is not able to select any nodes in the shadowDOM just by `d3.select`. Is there a way to get `d3` working inside `shadowdom` or am I missing something obvious?

In detail:

```dart
d3.select("#insideShadowDom")
```

does not return / select anything provided you have something like

```html
<web-component>
#document-fragment
   <div id="insideShadowDom"></div>
</web-component>
```

To clarify: The `shadowDOM` is generated by a framework. I found a way to get the initial `shadowRoot` (injected). However I'm still wondering if it is possible to tell `d3` about the `shadowDOM` even though I don't have the handle that `createShadowRoot()` returns.

Comment: Could you post an example please? I don't have any experience with shadow DOM but in principle you should be able to use D3 with it as far as I can tell.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can't cross DOM boundaries, i.e. the thing you select from has to be in the right DOM. So code like `elementInShadowDom.select("#insideShadowDom")` should work.

Comment: i am calling select on the d3 root object and it certainly does not return anything, but I'll check again. You suggest to call select on a dom element itself ?

Comment: Yes -- so something like `var foo = d3.select("...").append("..."); foo.select("...")`.

Comment: No, that doesn't open the shadowDOM for d3

Comment: Could you post an example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: i added a shadow-dom example.

Comment: [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/j3p3d/) works fine for me (in Chrome). Note that the second selector doesn't select anything as it would cross DOMs, but the third works fine.

Comment: Of course that works. You create the shadowDom by yourself and have a handle. I dont.

Comment: Well, your example works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/XNVr3/

Comment: yes, because once a shadowDOM is created this is not the markup that you can see in the code. the #document-fragement is just a marker to show you the code of the shadwDOM itself (generated by chrome). However, this is not what is actually in the DOM. In your example you could access this element only because you had a handle to it. The difference is that i want to access a shadowDOM that another script generates. Imagine your first example and trya to get the shadowDOM without having the handle that "createShadowDom" gives you.

Comment: You can do this by selecting `.webkitShadowRoot` (in Chrome) of the element that contains the shadow DOM -- http://jsfiddle.net/j3p3d/1/

Comment: Aaaaah, i did not stumble upon this call. Write this down as an answer and I'll gladly mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While DOM selectors won't work across DOMs, you can get access to a shadow root (at least in Chrome) through the `.webkitShadowRoot` property. Passing this to `d3.select()`, you can then select any elements in the shadow DOM as usual.

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3p3d/1/).

Comment: I know it's six years later but fwiw this example no longer works

Comment: Some of the functions have changed names --> http://jsfiddle.net/Lpa3kw1j/

Answer (score 5):

You can pass in object -- also, use var if you need to reference the object from a callback:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <div id="foobar"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            ready: function() {
                var foobar = this.$.foobar;
                someCallback(function() {
                    d3.select(foobar).
                    ...
                }); 
                ...
            }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, however, with the latest Polymer version (1.0.0) you can access shadow dom elements with:

```
<template> ... <div id="elementId"></div> ... </template>


Polymer({
    ready: function() { var svg = d3.select(this.$.elementId).append('svg'; }
});
```

This will allow you to render the chart and appropriately select the shadow dom element.